# Can I use the built in picasa share feature in my android app?

Tags: android, android-widget, picasa

I am trying to develop a app which can upload photo to different sites. In android phone gallery there is already a feature to share to picasa by default. Is there any way to call the same thing as it happens when the user click on share, picasa in gallery.

If not, what can be the other way to upload image to picasa.

Comment: have you looked at Picasa API?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing should be done with the ACTION_SEND Intent: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND

For example if you use this with a MIME type of image/*, the user will be prompted to select all of the things they can share an image with.  If Picassa is one of these on their device, it will be in the list.